# Drive no longer works on my Chrysler 300

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission, chrysler-300

I have 2006 300 Chrysler V6 Hemi engine AWD.

I went to start my car this morning, put it in drive, but it wouldn't go. Then I put it in reverse and it would drive back as well as neutral. So then I turned the car engine off and tried to turn it back on, and the engine wouldn't start at all. It would turn but the engine wouldn't start for about 30 minutes.

After I put my foot on the brakes and put the car in neutral then back in park, the car engine started again, but still wouldn't drive once I was able to put it in drive.

Can someone tell me what's going on with my car?

Comment: Could you edit the title to something that describes the problem? That way, people can see from the title if it's something they know about and can answer.

Comment: When you said it would turn, were you talking about the ignition key, or the engine?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly could be that the switch pack attached to the gear selector is faulty. That could explain all the faults, especially that the car wouldn't start without moving the selector, since this switch ensures the car wont start in anything other than neutral or park.

Comment: But OP said it would "turn" but not start. The gear selector switch would not even let it turn over unless in park or N, so if it is faulty and not recognizing position allowing start, it should not "turn", yes?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it. The description is a little confusing, but I came to the conclusion that they were talking about the ignition key turning, but the car wouldn't start.  Anything else doesn't make sense.

Comment: agreed, confusing description